# Ionic and Angular Google Maps Get directions

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

At the moment i have a map that can give directions from  preset point A to preset point B, but i would like to have directions from user location to a preset point like in this example:
http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map

My controller code is:

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $document, $ionicLoading) {
// map object
$scope.map = {
control: {},
center: {
    latitude: 51.51139,
    longitude: -0.2237284
},
zoom: 14
 };

 // marker object
 $scope.marker = {
 center: {
    latitude: 51.51139,
    longitude: -0.2237284
 }
}

// instantiate google map objects for directions

var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


// directions object -- with defaults
$scope.directions = {
origin: "this shoud be user ",
destination: "White City, London W12 7RQ",
 showList: false
 }

 // get directions using google maps api
 $scope.getDirections = function () {
  var request = {
  origin: $scope.directions.origin,
  destination: $scope.directions.destination,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };
  directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
   if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.map.control.getGMap());
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsList'));
    $scope.directions.showList = true;
  } else {
    alert('Google route unsuccesfull!');
  }
  });
}
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is it that you are asking? Do you want such UI? or do you want to show waypoints like it is in the example? Be more specific. Also, if you already have an example what "ideas" are those that you seek?

Comment: Thank you for your observations.
basically what i m looking for is to  display a map that won t give you the directions from two pre set points, but instead will locate the user (point A) and calculate the route to a preset point (B).I m not interested in having the same UI.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting direction service, get the location of the user like this:

```js
$scope.centerOnMe = function() {
  if (!$scope.map) {
    return;
  }

  $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Getting current location...',
  });

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    $scope.positions.push({
      lat: pos.k,
      lng: pos.B
    });
    console.log(pos);
    $scope.map.setCenter(pos);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  });
};
```

Then access the location you just got in your direction request like:

```js
// directions object -- with defaults
$scope.directions = 
  origin: pos.k + "," + pos.B,
  destination: "White City, London W12 7RQ",
  showList: false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. for some reasone i can't implement your suggestion into my code. This is the codepen i ve created: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wagRLj       Any advice?